# Could nodejs loop be asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

While this code is running i cant do anything. Is there asynchronous way for loops?

```
// This object is very large
var listOfUsers = {};

for(var key in listOfUsers){
  delete listOfUsers[key]  
}
```

Comment: Control structures don't have their own option to work with asynchronous operations, though they can be combined with other language features, such as [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). – Can you provide more details about what you're actually trying to do within the loop?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski It just move user to other object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there asynchronous way for loops?

No.  Since `delete listOfUsers[key]` is itself a synchronous operation, then there is no way to do anything else while that loop is running.  The JS interpreter is busy executing the loop and executing that `delete` operation.  Because Javascript in node.js is single threaded so there's only ever one set of Javascript executing at a time.  You can't execute anything else until the loop is done.

It occurs to me that if you're just trying to get `listOfUsers` back to an empty object and nobody else holds a reference to the original object, you could perhaps replace your existing loop with just this:

```
listOfUsers = {};
```

while would be a lot faster.  The old object (and its properties) would then get garbage collected.

---

In rare circumstances, you can solve problems like this and lessen the impact of a synchronous operation by breaking its operation into chunks and doing one chunk, then letting the event loop run and then do another chunk.

For example, you might be able to do something like this:

```
// remove all users, chunked to 100 at a time
// allowing the event loop to run between chunks
function removeUsers() {
    const chunkSize = 100;
    let usersToDelete = Object.keys(listOfUsers).slice(chunkSize);
    if (!usersToDelete.length) {
        // everything deleted, no more work to do
        return;
    } else {
    for (let key of usersToDelete) {
        delete listOfUsers[key];
    }
    // delete some more after other things get a chance to run in the event loop
    setTimeout(removeUsers, 20);
}
```

A problem with this approach is that you can't add any new users to the `listOfUsers` until this is done or they will get deleted.